# Select2 AJAX not showing "No data found" when no data in database, instead showing search parameter as option to select

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I've been working on a project where I've to load select2 option from ajax call.

The code is working fine, except in search result, it always shows search parameter as option. Even if there is no data in database, it still showing it as option, not showing "No data found".

My code is here

```
       $(".search_user").select2({
            minimumInputLength: 11,
            tags: [],
            ajax: {
                url: "/user/get_user",
                dataType: 'json',
                type: "GET",
                quietMillis: 250,
                data: function (term) {
                    return {
                        term: term
                    };
                },
                processResults: function (data) {
                    var Return = [];
                    for (var i in data.item) {
                        console.log(data.item[i])
                        if (data.item[i].id != data.item[i].text) {
                            Return.push(data.item[i]);
                        }
                    }
                    return {
                        results: Return
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

my return json is like this

```
{"item":[{"id":16,"name":"Razin Abid"}]}
```

My view is looking like this.

[image]

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

### If you using firemodal on stisla

```
$('#modal-create-promo').click(()=>{
    setTimeout(()=>{
        $('#fire-modal-1').removeAttr('tabindex');
    });
});

    $("#modal-create-promo").fireModal({
    ...
});
```

It's work for me

Answer (score 0):

Thats because you enable tags option from select2. You need to remove 'Tags:[]' from your code.

visit : https://select2.org/tagging

so, your code should be like this:

```
$(".search_user").select2({
        minimumInputLength: 11,
        ajax: {
            url: "/user/get_user",
            dataType: 'json',
            type: "GET",
            quietMillis: 250,
            data: function (term) {
                return {
                    term: term
                };
            },
            processResults: function (data) {
                var Return = [];
                for (var i in data.item) {
                    console.log(data.item[i])
                    if (data.item[i].id != data.item[i].text) {
                        Return.push(data.item[i]);
                    }
                }
                return {
                    results: Return
                }
            }
        }
    });
```